# Featureful terminal emulator for use with LXDE?

Tags: linux, open-source, gui, terminal-emulator

There are currently two terminal emulators I use on my desktop(s): When I'm running KDE I'm pretty satisfied with konsole; but when I run LXDE I don't want to bring that much up just to keep running konsole, so I use lxterminal.

The thing is, I'm not very pleased with it - it's missing a bunch of features (most but not all of them being present in konsole). So, I'm thinking of switching to something else. Question is, what should it be?

Required:

- Gratis
- Libre license
- Runs on Linux
- Wide feature set (I could be more specific but I don't want to limit potential answers in the interest of other people hitting this page)
- Relatively lightweight, marginally (that is, when you're working in LXDE rather than, say, KDE or Gnome loaded)

Desirable:

- Under continued development / active maintenance
- Large user base

Comment: What features do you miss in LXTerminal?

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty happy with [Terminator](https://gnometerminator.blogspot.de/p/introduction.html). It is written in Python and based on the GNOME terminal (and its [performance](https://gnometerminator.blogspot.de/2015/08/why-write-terminator-in-python-it-is.html) should be roughly the same). The main feature is that you can create (with shortcuts) multiple terminals in one window:

[image: Terminator Screenshot]

You should be able to install it with `sudo apt-get install terminator` (or your equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

[tmux](https://tmux.github.io/)
ok, technically it's not a term emulator, but it's powerfull and lightweigh, and you can run it inside the term of your choice !

Comment: Indeed, that is not an answer to my question.

Comment: Forth, please describe how to use it in easy-to-understand steps with screenshots, thanks!

Comment: Also, please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality and apply it to your answer.